# How does listing files/folders inside of google drive work?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have been reading the reference and also used the API explorer, but I cannot for the life of me manage to get a full list of what's inside a specific folder of my google drive.

As far as I understand, the following code should list all files inside the folder that has the given folderID. That does work; **but only on files that I created from my app**. Folders/files created with or uploaded through the web UI will not show up in the response.

```
const folders = await drive.files.list({
    q: "'<folderID>' in parents",
    trashed: false,
    spaces: ['drive']
});
```

In a different post I found that the scope might be the issue, but as far as I know I have already given my app the highest available scope:

`const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];`

I appreciate any help on this matter. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symptoms are consistent with using `drive.file` scope instead of `drive`. Is it possible that you granted access using `drive.file` and haven't yet repeated the grant procedure with `drive`?

The other possible explanation is that you are in two different Drive Accounts. Many people use a Service Account because the Google docs refer to this as server-to-server, without realising that the Service Account is a totally different account to their User Account, ie. the one with the Drive UI. So your app will be uploading and reading files in the Service Account, your UI-created files are in your User Account.

Comment: That was it! At some point I must have edited the scope without re-authorizing. Thank you very much for taking some time out of your day to help me. You're the man!